# How to Find All Configuration Files in My .NET Core Program?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, command-line, config

I have to adjust the Configuration files of my .NET Core program but I don't know how many Configuration files I have and where they are in the program. I hope you can help me to find and locate all configuration files in my program.

I tried these commands in the command shell:
find . -type f -name "*.config" -o -name "*.json" -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.yaml" -o -name "*.yml"

Furthermore:
find . -type f ( -name "*.config" -o -name "*.json" -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.yaml" -o -name "*.yml" )

But it doesn't work. The output is always that file "*.json" is not found.

Comment: Are you talking about searching in source code or deployed program? Why exactly do you need to find them?

Comment: Its your program and you don't know what config files it uses? We need a bit of background for that to help. And it doesn't look like a programming problem? If its just about the usage of a "find" cli command you might rather want to ask on something like "Super User".

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Sorry, it's my first question, and I needed to clarify it further. This program belongs to my company. I have already refactored the program to .NET Core and therefore I have to adjust the configuration file(s) right now.